# POST from jQuery Select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[**JsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cfh77t0f/)

```
<body>
<form method="POST" name="my">
<ol id="selectable">
  <li class="ui-widget-content" id="0">1</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content" id="1">2</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content" id="2">3</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content" id="3">4</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content" id="4">5</li>
</ol>
</form>
</body>
```

I want to get the select menu in the response from backend. I was able to change the diplayed value according to selection but can't figure out how to receive input from the selected input. Please help me!

Comment: can u please provide in details that what are you trying to do here?

Comment: I want to get or print `5` if an user select 5. Just want to get the response from the select.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to post this value to the server so it can do some calculations with it, or that you just want the value?

Comment: i have checked it and it is printing the value in console fine so whats wrong wih this?

Comment: I meant that I wanted to get it from response not just in HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could leverage the `selected` method, which provides you two arguments in the callback, the `event` and the `ui` object.

The `ui` object contains the `selected` object, which is the native DOM element. In this way, we can wrap it and then use jQuery methods against it (merely for clarity and cohesion)

From there, we can construct the `$.ajax()` call to the server and perform our request. One possible way would be:

```
selected: function (event, ui) {
    var $f = $('form[name="my"]'); //cache reference to the form wrapper
    $.ajax({
        url: $f.prop('action'),
        type: $f.prop('method'),
        data: {
            val: $(ui.selected).text() // this is the selected val.
        }
    }).done(function (data) {
        console.log(data); //return from server
    });
}
```

Now in your page that processes the server request, `action="path/to/my/script.ext"` you can access the value selected through `val`, such as `$_POST['val'];` for instance.

Answer (score 0):

**Js Fiddle**

you will get the selected text when you click on the menu